Python, Pandas удаляет столбец с данными и вставляет пустую строку
Столкнулся с проблемой: при создании фрейма данных pandas удаляет один столбец с данными и вставляет вторую строку с пустыми значениями. Как это исправить?
import pandas as pd
import json
from io import StringIO
        
List_Objects = [{'CadastralNumber': '37:24:01024'},
                        {'DateCreated': '2011-12-09+04:00'},
                        {'FoundationDate': ''},
                        {'Area': '5462'},
                        {'AssignationBuilding': '204003000000'},
                        {'CadastralBlock': '37:24:010246'},
                        {'CadastralCost': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost_Value': '163292388.96'},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApplicationDate': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApplicationLastDate': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/CodeDocument': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/Date': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/Desc': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/IssueOrgan': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/Name': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/Number': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/ApprovalDocument/Series': ''},
                        {'CadastralCost/DateApproval': '2012-09-27+04:00'},
                        {'CadastralCost/DateEntering': '2012-10-09+04:00'},
                        {'CadastralCost/DateValuation': '2011-12-10+04:00'},
                        {'CadastralCost/RevisalStatementDate': ''},
                        {'CarParkingSpacesCadastralNumbers': ''},
                        {'CarParkingSpacesCadastralNumbers/CadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/AssignmentEGROKN': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/AssignmentEGROKN/NameCultural': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/AssignmentEGROKN/ObjCultural': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/AssignmentEGROKN/RegNum': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/CodeDocument': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/Date': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/Desc': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/IssueOrgan': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/Name': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/Number': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/Document/Series': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/InclusionEGROKN': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/InclusionEGROKN/NameCultural': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/InclusionEGROKN/ObjCultural': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/InclusionEGROKN/RegNum': ''},
                        {'CulturalHeritage/RequirementsEnsure': ''},
                        {'ElementsConstruct': ''},
                        {'ElementsConstruct/Material': None},
                        {'ElementsConstruct/Material_Wall': '061001007001'},
                        {'ExploitationChar': None},
                        {'ExploitationChar_YearBuilt': '1978'},
                        {'ExploitationChar_YearUsed': ''},
                        {'FacilityCadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'FacilityCadastralNumber/CadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'FacilityCadastralNumber/Name': ''},
                        {'FacilityCadastralNumber/Purpose': ''},
                        {'FlatsCadastralNumbers': ''},
                        {'FlatsCadastralNumbers/CadastralNumber': '37:24'},
                        {'Floors': None},
                        {'Floors_Floors': '6'},
                        {'Floors_UndergroundFloors': '1'},
                        {'Location': ''},
                        {'Location_AddressOrLocation': ''},
                        {'Location/Apartment': ''},
                        {'Location/Apartment_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/Apartment_Value': ''},
                        {'Location/City': None},
                        {'Location/City_Name': 'Иваново'},
                        {'Location/City_Type': 'Г'},
                        {'Location/District': ''},
                        {'Location/District_Name': ''},
                        {'Location/District_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/FIAS': ''},
                        {'Location/KLADR': '37000001000074600'},
                        {'Location/Level1': None},
                        {'Location/Level1_Type': 'Д.'},
                        {'Location/Level1_Value': '35'},
                        {'Location/Level2': ''},
                        {'Location/Level2_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/Level2_Value': ''},
                        {'Location/Level3': ''},
                        {'Location/Level3_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/Level3_Value': ''},
                        {'Location/Locality': ''},
                        {'Location/Locality_Name': ''},
                        {'Location/Locality_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/Note': ''},
                        {'Location/OKATO': '24401000000'},
                        {'Location/OKTMO': ''},
                        {'Location/Other': ''},
                        {'Location/PostalCode': ''},
                        {'Location/ReadableAddress': ''},
                        {'Location/Region': '37'},
                        {'Location/RussianFederation': 'Российская Федерация'},
                        {'Location/SovietVillage': ''},
                        {'Location/SovietVillage_Name': ''},
                        {'Location/SovietVillage_Type': ''},
                        {'Location/Street': None},
                        {'Location/Street_Name': ''},
                        {'Location/Street_Type': 'Ул'},
                        {'Location/UrbanDistrict': ''},
                        {'Location/UrbanDistrict_Name': ''},
                        {'Location/UrbanDistrict_Type': ''},
                        {'Name': 'Многоквартирный Дом'},
                        {'ObjectPermittedUses': ''},
                        {'ObjectPermittedUses/ObjectPermittedUse': ''},
                        {'ObjectType': '002001002000'},
                        {'ParentCadastralNumbers': ''},
                        {'ParentCadastralNumbers/CadastralNumber': '37:24:010'},
                        {'PrevCadastralNumbers': ''},
                        {'PrevCadastralNumbers/CadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'PreviouslyPosted': 'True'},
                        {'SubBuildings': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding_NumberRecord': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding_DateCreated': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Area': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/CodeDocument': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/Date': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/Desc': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/IssueOrgan': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/Name': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/Number': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Document/Series': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Name': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Registration': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Registration/RegistrationDate': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Registration/RightNumber': ''},
                        {'SubBuildings/SubBuilding/Encumbrances/Type': ''},
                        {'UnitedCadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'UnitedCadastralNumber/CadastralNumber': ''},
                        {'UnitedCadastralNumber/Name': ''},
                        {'UnitedCadastralNumber/Purpose': ''},
                        {'CadastralNumberOKS': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/AssignationBuilding': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/AssignationName': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/CadastralNumberOKS': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ElementsConstruct': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ElementsConstruct/Material': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ElementsConstruct/Material_Wall': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ExploitationChar': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ExploitationChar_YearBuilt': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ExploitationChar_YearUsed': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/Floors': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/Floors_Floors': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/Floors_UndergroundFloors': ''},
                        {'ParentOKS/ObjectType': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject_Number': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject_Type': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Position': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Position_NumberOnPlan': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Position_Description': ''},
                        {'AssignationName': ''},
                        {'KeyParameters': ''},
                        {'KeyParameters/KeyParameter': ''},
                        {'KeyParameters/KeyParameter_Type': ''},
                        {'KeyParameters/KeyParameter_Value': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction_NumberRecord': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction_DateCreated': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/CodeDocument': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/Date': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/Desc': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/IssueOrgan': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/Name': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/Number': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Document/Series': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Name': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Registration': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Registration/RegistrationDate': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Registration/RightNumber': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/Encumbrances/Type': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/KeyParameter': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/KeyParameter_Type': ''},
                        {'SubConstructions/SubConstruction/KeyParameter_Value': ''},
                        {'Assignation': ''},
                        {'Assignation/AssignationCode': ''},
                        {'Assignation/AssignationType': ''},
                        {'Assignation/AuxiliaryFlat': ''},
                        {'Assignation/SpecialType': ''},
                        {'Assignation/TotalAssets': ''},
                        {'CadastralNumberFlat': ''},
                        {'Location/RoomNumber': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level_Number': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level_Type': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level/Position': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level/Position_NumberOnPlan': ''},
                        {'PositionInObject/Level/Position_Description': ''},
                        {'SubFlats': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat_NumberRecord': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat_DateCreated': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Area': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/CodeDocument': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/Date': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/Desc': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/IssueOrgan': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/Name': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/Number': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Document/Series': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Name': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Registration': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Registration/RegistrationDate': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Registration/RightNumber': ''},
                        {'SubFlats/SubFlat/Encumbrances/Type': ''},
                        {'DegreeReadiness': ''}]
        
        
        
        
json_data = json.dumps(List_Objects)
df = pd.read_json(StringIO(json_data))
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print(df)
print(len(List_Objects))

    
     CadastralNumber  ... DegreeReadiness
 0  37:24:010246:397  ...                
 1               NaN  ...             NaN
        
[2 rows x 212 columns]
 213
        
Process finished with exit code 0


ну так вы же сами вроде бы делаете dropna,а потом еще и превращаете это в Series.

вы методом .dropna удаляете все nan в каждом столбце, затем "сжимая" эти столбцы с помощью pd.Series до значимых ячеек. а значимых ячеек у вас везде по одной (отсюда первая строка в результате), кроме столбца PositionInObject - там значимых ячеек - две - отсюда и вторая строка в результате, где значения во всех колонках - становятся nan, кроме колонки PositionInObject.
df = pd.DataFrame(List_Objects)
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print(df.loc[:, "PositionInObject"].values)

['' '']


Спасибо, очевидные вещи лежат на поверхности.
